# Does Heedless Charge, Domino Rush and Improved Trip work together?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I have a fighter with Power Attack, Leap Attack, Improved Trip, Improved Bull Rush, Shock Trooper and Combat Reflexes, who has a reach weapon (Guisarme).

Let's assume that I am in a charging range of enemy A and I can Bull Rush him towards enemy B.

Can I do the following sequence? And if not, what parts of this did I misunderstand and can they be replaced with something else?

1. I charge, using Power Attack/Leap Attack to use Heedless Charge (part of Shock Trooper)
2. Instead of attacking (at first), I use Directed Bull Rush (part of Shock Trooper) to attempt to knock enemy A into enemy B (stopping 10ft. short of the collided enemies rather than adjacent)
3. I use Domino Rush (part of Shock Trooper) and Improved Trip on both enemies and afterwards attack them both because of Improved Trip and cannot be tripped in return.

Now, the outcome:

- The free Attacks from Improved Trip deal full Power Attack/Leap Attack damage
- The penalty from Power Attack goes to AC due to Heedless Charge (I *did* charge and Power Attack in the end)

Is this sequence allowed?

Edit:

Thanks a lot for your answers. I now have only two things unclear - whether or not Leap Attack and Heedless Charge apply. I think, the crucial part is the time, when charge is considered completed.

Becouse benefits of Leap Attack:

> You can combine a jump with a charge against an opponent. If you cover at least 10 feet of horizontal distance with your jump, and you end your jump in a square from which you threaten your target, you deal +100% the normal bonus damage from your use of the Power Attack feat. If you use this tactic with a two-handed weapon, you instead triple the extra damage from Power Attack.
>   This attack must follow all the normal rules for using the Jump skill and for making a charge, except that you ignore rough terrain in any squares you jump over.

and benefit of Heedless Charge

> Heedless Charge: To use this maneuver, you must charge and make the attack at the end of the charge using your Power Attack feat. The penalty you take on your attack roll must be -5 or worse. In addition to normal charge modifiers (which give you a -2 penalty to AC and a +2 bonus on the attack roll), you can assign any portion of the attack roll penalty from Power Attack to your Armor Class instead, up to a maximum equal to your base attack bonus.

Suggest, that if I make attack at the end of a charge with Power Attack, they both apply (so is the usual charge bonus to attack roll).

And if charge is ended when i chose to use Bull Rush instead of Attack, then i do not get benefit of both Leap attack and Heedless Charge and charge bonus to attack when i do Trip Attacks (but at the same time, i should have penalty from charge and power attack until the start of my turn)

But if charge is consodered finished after all my actions - like Bull Rush and Trip and Attack afterwards it seems, that i should get the benefits and charge bonus.

Can you please explain this to me?

Comment: I found your question to be quite difficult to follow, so I edited it for more clarity. Feel free to rollback (click on "edited xyz ago", then "rollback") or to edit it some more yourself, especially if I got something about your question wrong. I also removed the parts about Robilar's Gambit and Elusive Target, because they have little to do with this question, but might warrant a question on their own.

Comment: @MrLemon thanks, that's exactly what i wanted to ask. In Robilar's Gambit and Elusive Target part i wanted to know, if i could make AoO as part of this maneouvre **while charging**. Since until i trip both enemies and hit them (or failed some checks or ended in some other way) I am considered as charging? Or charge ends when i start Bull Rush?

Comment: Although I found the mental image of a *Head*-less Charge quite amusing, I've corrected it to *Heedless*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The Round in Steps

1. The fighter employs the feat [Power Attack](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#powerAttack) (*PH* 98) before taking actions to suffer a -6 penalty to attack rolls and gain a +6 bonus to damage with 1-handed weapons and a +12 bonus to damage with 1-handed weapons wielded in 2 hands and 2-handed weapons. This is not an action.
2. The fighter takes a full-round action to make a [charge](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialAttacks.htm#charge). During the charge the fighter makes a [Jump](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/jump.htm) skill check (DC 10 if the fighter first moves in a straight line at least 20 ft. otherwise DC 20) to clear at least 10 ft. of distance--ending his movement in a square that threatens the foe--, to get the benefits of the feat Leap Attack (*CAd* 110).
3. Instead of making an attack at the charge's end, the fighter attempts a [bull rush](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialAttacks.htm#bullRush). Because of the charge the fighter gains a +2 bonus on the bull rush attempt. Because of the attempted bull rush rather than the attack, the Shock Trooper (*CW* 112) feat's tactical maneuver heedless charge is unused, and the benefits of the feat Leap Attack don't apply.
4. Using the Shock Trooper feat's directed bull rush tactical maneuver, the fighter (presumably) successfully bull rushes the charge victim into another nearby foe. Using the Shock Trooper feat's domino rush tactical maneuver, the fighter makes [trip](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialAttacks.htm#trip) attempts against both foes.

   It's up to the DM whether the tactical maneuver domino rush permits the fighter to make trip attempts against creatures he doesn't threaten. The tactical maneuver seems intended to allow that (knocking foes into each other and proning them after they collide), but nothing in the tactical maneuver *says* that's allowed, so it may default to the trip rules, which don't permit tripping creatures one doesn't threaten. A weapon with sufficient reach may be needed if intending to launch foes *then* trip them. Ask the DM.
5. If a trip attempt is successful *and* the foe remains within the fighter's threatened area, the tripped foe is subject to the fighter's free attack from the feat [Improved Trip](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#improvedTrip) (*PH* 96). Each attack the feat Improved Trip generates gains the benefits of the feat Power Attack.

The feat Leap Attack requires a charge be ended threatening the charge's target and that attack *at the charge's end* gets the listed bonuses. The sentences aren't discrete, and can't be read individually, and the feat says so ("This attack [the one at the charge's end] must follow all the normal rules for using the Jump skill and for making a charge").

The Shock Trooper feat's tactical maneuver heedless charge suffers the same way: "To use this maneuver, you must charge and make the attack" at the charge's end, and if the fighter doesn't make the attack, making instead a bull rush attempt, the heedless charge tactical maneuver can't be used.

Extra attacks generated as *results* of charging (such as those made as a benefit of the feat Improved Trip) just *aren't* the attack at the charge's end, even though the attacks *are* generated after the charge occurs. Those extra attacks from the feat Improved Trip don't get the benefits of the feat Leap Attack and the tactical maneuver heedless charge.

The feat Shock Trooper essentially lets a character do his choice of crazy things on a charge: *either* pinball his enemies *or* deal damage while endangering himself. He can't, using that feat, do both.

(This sequence is unaffected by the Elusive Target (*CW* 110) feat's tactical maneuver cause overreach and the feat Robilar's Gambit (*PH2* 82). Those feats function normally.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have doubts About 4 though: I make trip with a Guisarme, it's a reach weapon a I do have 10ft reach and threaten enemies.

Comment: And will Leap Attack and Headless Charge apply when I charge an enemy and try to Trip before attack? The benefit of Imp Trip sounds like it may work - **If you trip an opponent in melee combat, you immediately get a melee attack against that opponent as if you hadn't used your attack for the trip attempt.**

Comment: I agree about those feats and how charge work - this time i'm looking at trip attack. I mean - even without Improved trip - it is a melee attack, i can apply Power Attack to it."You can try to trip an opponent as an unarmed **melee attack**" (and not unarmed if weapon is capable of Trip). And then the wording above   make it seem that attack after trip should be consideres as if trip did not applied at all. I mean, there is also a Knockdown feat, that allows you a free trip attempt after you deal more then 10 damage. It really seems like it can go both ways, or is it not?

Comment: @Shf Sure, at the end of the charge the fighter can trip instead of making a melee attack (*PH* 141, Table 8-2, footnote 7) and *probably* get the charge's bonuses on the attack granted by the feat Improved Trip if the trip's successful, but doing so prevents all the bull rush shenanigans the original question asks. I suggest a new stand-alone question about that to solicit other opinions.

Comment: There is also Knockback (RoS p.142) feat to probably allow the sequence asked first. Also size and spiked chain both can help with reach issues.

Answer (score 0):

> is this sequence legit or i have some parts of it misunderstood?

The sequence is not entirely legit, because a Bull Rush attempt does not deal damage. In addition, you only get one attack as part of a charge. However, because of Improved Trip, you get an attack against every tripped opponent, where you can use part of the sequence.

According to the SRD:

> You can make a bull rush as a standard action (an attack) or as part of a charge. When you make a bull rush, you attempt to push an opponent straight back **instead of damaging him**. You can only bull rush an opponent who is one size category larger than you, the same size, or smaller.

Therefore, you can activate Power Attack on your Bull Rush attempt against the target, but if will not deal any damage. However, if you succeed in tripping the opponent by using the *Directed Bull Rush* and *Domino Rush* maneuvers, you get an immediate attack against every enemy you tripped thanks to Improved Trip:

> If you trip an opponent in melee combat, you immediately get a melee attack against that opponent as if you hadn't used your attack for the trip attempt.

In addition, you **can** use the effects of the *Heedless Charge* maneuver to assign the to-hit penalty to your AC, if and only if you used Power Attack to subtract from the to-hit of your Bull Rush attempt:

> To use this maneuver, you must charge and make the attack at the end of the charge using your Power Attack feat.

So you can deal Power Attack damage, with a penalty to AC instead of the to-hit roll.

**However**, Leap Attack does nothing, because of a very important rule of the Charge action:

> Even if you have extra attacks, such as from having a high enough base attack bonus or from using multiple weapons, you only get to make one attack during a charge.

Therefore, only the Bull Rush attempt counts as your charging attack.

> And if i have let's say Elusive target , will i be able to Trip everyone, who makes AoO and misses me while i move with Cause Overreach?

Yes, and you will also be granted an attack on a successful trip on these targets, because of Improved Trip.

> And can i squize in a Robilar's Gambit somewhere here in between and again Trip everyone as AoO?

Yes, and you will also be granted an attack on a successful trip on these targets, because of Improved Trip. Note however, that these trip attempts are resolved after they have made an attack on you.

Edit: in regards to your comment:

> i wanted to know, if i could make AoO as part of this maneouvre while charging.

No, you only count as charging during the Bull Rush attempt (or any other attack you make at the end of a charge).